# create a map in Go using reflection

Tags: json, go, reflection

I'm just playing around trying to write a JSON reader wrapper in Golang that is pleasant to use like jsoncpp. Is it possible to create a map with a dynamic type in Golang?

For instance:

```
package main

import  "reflect"

func main() {
    i := 1                       // type int
    myType := reflect.TypeOf(i)  // type Type
    a := make(map[string]myType) // make a map of Type
    a["KEY"] = i                 // Assign an int to the map
}
```

Am I dreaming?

Some people would say "That's why Go have the type `interface{}`", however, I don't want be doing something like this:

```
myMap["key"].(map[string]string)["subKey1"].([]map[string]interface)["subKey2"].(int)
```

I want to do something like this:

```
myMap["key"]["subKey1"][0]["subKey2"]
```

Perhaps a good soul have already coded a wrapper like this before but I couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: Why not just use the standard `json` package, and unmarshal into a struct?

Comment: There's nothing in Go that would allow you to do what you want and how you want because Go is a statically typed langauge, `myType` has to be known at compile time. The most "dynamic" version you can get is to use `interface{}`, otherwise you'll have to know the type beforehand and allocate a map from that. If you want jsoncpp like functionality, Go may not be the language for that... The next best thing is to implement getter methods on a custom map type, e.g. MyMap.GetString("key.subKey1[0].subKey2"), you can find such implementations on github.

Comment: @TTKDroid, just to add a bit of clarification to my previous comment, you *can* use `reflect` to create a map of any given type, nested to whatever depth. But to be able to use it how you want will not be possible, you'll always have to do type assertion on the map value. That is, you can create `myMap` with `reflect` but you cannot do this `myMap["KEY"] = i` nor this `myMap["key"]["subKey1"][0]["subKey2"]` without first doing `myMap.(T)`.

Comment: It is possible to create a map dynamically of any key/value type dynamically

Comment: As @mkopriva stated in order to make a dynamic map usable, you would still need to build a wrapper around it  i.e: https://github.com/viant/toolbox/tree/master/data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is example to how to create dynamic map.

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var key = "key1"
    var value = 123

    var keyType = reflect.TypeOf(key)
    var valueType = reflect.TypeOf(value)
    var aMapType = reflect.MapOf(keyType, valueType)
    aMap := reflect.MakeMapWithSize(aMapType, 0)
    aMap.SetMapIndex(reflect.ValueOf(key), reflect.ValueOf(value))
    fmt.Printf("%T:  %v\n", aMap.Interface(), aMap.Interface())

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)



func main() {
    key := 1
    value := "abc"

    mapType := reflect.MapOf(reflect.TypeOf(key), reflect.TypeOf(value))

    mapValue := reflect.MakeMap(mapType)
    mapValue.SetMapIndex(reflect.ValueOf(key), reflect.ValueOf(value))
    mapValue.SetMapIndex(reflect.ValueOf(2), reflect.ValueOf("def"))
    mapValue.SetMapIndex(reflect.ValueOf(3), reflect.ValueOf("gh"))

    keys := mapValue.MapKeys()
    for _, k := range keys {
        c_key := k.Convert(mapValue.Type().Key())
        c_value := mapValue.MapIndex(c_key)
        fmt.Println("key :", c_key, " value:", c_value)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Will try that one as well!